# Using PHP's mysqli connection as an object for other classes

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have the following code which consists of class `DB` that establishes a connection with the SQL database using mysqli.

```
<?php
class DB
{
    private $mysqlilink;
    private $errors;
    function __construct($errors = array())
    {
        $this -> errors = $errors;
        $this -> connect();
    }

    function connect()
    {
        $server = "127.0.0.1";
        $user_name = "un";
        $password = "pw";
        $database = "db";

        if ($this -> mysqlilink == null)
        {
            $this -> mysqlilink = new mysqli($server, $user_name, $password, $database);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }
        }
        return $this -> mysqlilink;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $stmt -> close();
    }
}
?>
```

I have plans to use *at least* one class (in its own script file) with dedicated PHP functions that access the database for various parts of the website. After importing this script above, how do I link to it and make a call to the database through the object's connection? I am using the following code:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
class PageFunctions
{

    function printText()
    {
        if ($stmt = $this -> mysqlilink -> prepare("SELECT Text, MoreText FROM mytext WHERE id = 1"))
        {
            $stmt -> execute(); $stmt -> store_result();
            $rows = $stmt -> num_rows;
            if ($rows == 0) { return 'Database Not Found'; }
            else
            {
                $stmt -> bind_result($returnedText, $moreReturnedText); // Output variable(s)
                while ($stmt -> fetch()) // Return results
                {
                    return 'First text: ' . $returnedText . ' Second text: ' . $moreReturnedText;
                }
            }
            $stmt -> free_result();
            return;
        }
        else { printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $this -> mysqlilink -> error); }
    }
}
?>
```

To reiterate, I need to use the first code sample as a class that forms an object in multiple other classes/code files like the second code sample. Since I am new to PHP object orientation I was unable to successfully accomplish this, so I thought I'd ask for some expert advice before I come up with a bad solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for Dependency Injection. There are other ways, but this is the best practice.

```
//create an object of the DB class
$DB = new DB();

//create a PageFunctions object and pass the DB object into it as a dependency
$PF = new PageFunctions($DB);

//call your function from PageFunctions
$PF->myFunction();

//follow these concepts and do whatever you want!
```

You can make this work by setting a constructor for PageFunctions:

```
class PageFunctions() {

   //we don't want to accidentally change DB, so lets make it private;
   private $DB; 

   //this is the class constructor
   //the constructor is called when instantiating the class - new PageFunctions()
   public function __construct(DB $DB) {
     //now the DB object is available anywhere in this class!
     $this->DB = $DB;
   }
   //sample function
   public function myFunction() {
     $this->DB->connect();
   }
}
```

So, anytime you need to use a class within another class, make an instance (object) of it (or use an existing one) and pass it into the new class that needs it when creating an instance of it.

You might see this behavior accomplished using a Dependency Injection container, but it is still the same concept, system, and result. It's just a bit more abstracted. As you might have noticed from my explanation there, if you have a lot of classes that depend on other classes, that depend on other classes, etc, it can get quite overwhelming manually creating the instances and passing them in. A dependency injection container is nice because it lets you tell it how to make each class, and then it will take care of putting them altogether.

Comment: I implemented our solution but I am getting two errors. Did I misunderstand your instructions? Apologies for slightly differing variable and function names from the original question's samples. All 3 code files and error are here http://pastebin.com/QCva7hDK Thanks

Comment: @Keavon it looks like you tried to use something like `$this->mysqlilink` from within the PageIndex class. That's a property of DB which you passed in. PageIndex doesn't absorb the DB, it gets the DB as its own DB, so you need to access that property like `$this->DB->$mysqlilink`. Don't forget to accept my answer if you appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to upvote and accept the answer when I make it work. I added `DB ->` which got rid of the first `Notice` it was producing, but I get this error: `Fatal error: Cannot access private property DB::$mysqlilink in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\includes\page_index.php on line 19`

Comment: @Keavon Private properties can only be accessed within the class itself (a method of DB). You therefore can't directly access the property from an instance of it. The standard practice is to use getters/setters, aka mutators to get or set private variables. Basically, `public function getMysqliLink() { return $this->mysqliLink; }` and then `$this->DB->getMysqliLink()`. That's quite a bit out of the scope of your question :)

Comment: SomeKittensUx2666 No need to prod. I know how the site works and I wouldn't forget.  @m59 I'm not sure that it goes out of the scope of my question, because the question asks how to make the code I provided work, so I believe it's still in the scope. Thanks for providing your support thus far, but I am still very confused by your last comment. I hate to ask people to write my code for me, but it's still unclear. Could you please create a new Pastebin from http://pastebin.com/n6PnhCKM with the changes needed? Again, sorry for asking you to write my code but I'm having trouble understanding you.

Comment: @Keavon I'm sorry, but I'm not going to do that. I'm glad to help if you approach this with a humble attitude. I know what it's like to not understand and need personal help, so I want to be there for you. However, you are clearly demonstrating that you do not know how this site works (or at least is meant to work). Your question does not say "how do I make my code work" and if it did, I would have voted to close it because it is inappropriate for SO. Now, what specific thing about my previous explanation do you not understand? public vs. private variables, or getters/setters? or both?

Comment: My question was how not "fix my code" and I understand that is not appropriate on SO or SE. I was asking how to use the first class I provided in the second class I provided and you gave an answer which was very general. It's perfectly acceptable to assume I was asking specifically what code is needed. I'm not saying your answer is bad, but it is missing a complete example. It would be best if you could edit the answer to include the third script and the other needed code (like the getting/setter) in the other script(s). This way it would be easier for other readers to solve their problems too

Comment: I'm happy to work with you in the comments to get this to work; regarding the clarification from your 2nd comment, I didn't understand which scripts those two lines should go in. It sounds and looks like the first line goes in the `DB` class, but I was unable to figure out where the second line goes (which file and where in the file). I tried putting it in several different places, but I ended up mutilating the scripts and causing many more errors. I am also wondering if there are any additional things needed to properly connect the DB object to the script and print the text from the database.

Comment: @Keavon The things you're asking about aren't needed and there's no way I can answer it for you without writing the application myself. Join me for a chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46380/keavon-chat